# Encryption and Decryption of multiple files in android

Tags: java, android, file, encryption

Can any one tell me what i'm doing wrong in my code! I'm not getting any error though. Image file is encrypted but when i do decryption i couldn't view the image. It's still showing like an encrypted one. Correct me if i'm wrong. I'm new to this encryption and decryption. Thanks before.

And if your down voting you better tell me what's wrong and why is the reason you doing that!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button1, button2;

String KEY = "MyKey";
SparseArray<byte[]> array = new SparseArray<byte[]>();
SparseArray<byte[]> decryptArray = new SparseArray<byte[]>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           try {
               new EncryptAsyncTask().execute();
           } catch (Exception e) {  
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
    });

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                new DecryptAsyncTask().execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


   public class EncryptAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

   ProgressDialog mDialog;

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please wait");
   }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         byte[] incrept = null;
        try {
            getImageFile();
            if(array!=null && array.size()>0){
                for(int i=0 ; i<array.size() ; i++){
                    byte[] byteArray = array.get(i);
                    incrept = encrypt(KEY, byteArray);
                     FileOutputStream fos = null;
                        try {
                            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                                   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator
                                    +"EncryptedImages"+File.separator+i+"_Image.jpg"));
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            fos.write(incrept);
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }               
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(mDialog.isShowing()){
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
 }

 public class DecryptAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

   ProgressDialog mDialog;

   @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
    mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please wait");
}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         byte[] incrept = null;
        try {
            getImageFileFromSdCard();
            if(decryptArray!=null && decryptArray.size()>0){
                for(int i=0 ; i<decryptArray.size() ; i++){
                    byte[] byteArray = decryptArray.get(i);
                    incrept = decrypt(KEY, byteArray);                        
                     FileOutputStream fos = null;
                        try {
                            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                                   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator
                                    +"DecryptedImages"+File.separator+i+"_Image.jpg"));
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            fos.write(incrept);
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }               
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public byte[]   getImageFile() throws FileNotFoundException
{
  byte[] Image_data = null;
  byte[] arry = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Images"+File.separator);
        if(file.exists() && file.isDirectory()){
            File[] listOfImages = file.listFiles();
            if(listOfImages.length>0){
                 for(int i=0; i<listOfImages.length; i++){
                     byte[] inarry = null;
                     InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(listOfImages[i]));
                     int length = is.available();
                        Image_data = new byte[length];

                        int bytesRead;
                        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        while ((bytesRead = is.read(Image_data)) != -1)
                        {
                            output.write(Image_data, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                      inarry = output.toByteArray();
                      array.put(i, inarry);
                      is.close();
                 }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return arry;
}

public void getImageFileFromSdCard() throws FileNotFoundException
{
try {
    File file = new            File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"EncryptedImages"+File.separator);
    if(file.exists() && file.isDirectory()){
        File[] listOfFiles = file.listFiles();
        if(listOfFiles.length>0){
            for(int i=0 ; i<listOfFiles.length ; i++){
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(listOfFiles[i]);
                byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) listOfFiles[i].length()];
                fileInputStream.read(bFile);
                fileInputStream.close();
                decryptArray.put(i, bFile);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public  byte[] encrypt(String seed, byte[] cleartext) throws Exception {

    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext);
        return result;
}

public  byte[] decrypt(String seed, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = encrypted;
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);

        return result;
}

private  byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr); 
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
} 


private  byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.update(clear);
        return encrypted;
}

private  byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.update(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
}
 }
```

Comment: your code is very complicated for what you are trying to do. perhaps start with a simple array of bytes, learn how to encrypt/decrypt that array, then add your file handling. It is currently too hard to determine whether your code is reversible without running and debugging it, which is too much effort

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what are you trying to do.
It looks from the code that you are creating one byte array that includes all the files from the directory...

How do you suppose to encrypt and decrypt and break it back to files ?

daniel

Comment: I went through few set of code blocks and followed them. May be I'm wrong. But this encryption and decryption confuses me still. Can you help me! @danysz

Answer (score 0):

You are generating two different keys for encrypt and decrypt operations. You use the same seed, but different MODEs.

AES is symmetric, you use the same key to decrypt as to encrypt.

Comment: How can i do that @charlieS?

Comment: change getRawKey so it only generates a new one once, then re-use the same key on subsequent calls.